# После сборки webpack проект на vue не работает

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Установил vuejs через `vue init webpack-simple .`
Сделал небольшое приложение, собрал его командой `npm run build`, получил папку /dist/ с двумя файлами build.js и build.js.map

Выгружаю оба файла на сайт, например в директорию domain.ru/test/
Добавляю туда файл index.html с таким содержимым

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Страница раздела</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/test/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Захожу на сайт и ничего не работает, в консоль выводятся сообщения о работе приложения (там в некоторых местах есть console.log), но ничего не рендерится. Куда копать надо?

Comment: Сравните свой index.html, с тем, что создал webpack в папке dist

Answer (score 0):

Надо смотреть настройки вебпака, build должен выгрузить в папку dist всё - и index.html, и скрипты, и статику. То что в dist только два файла - это не нормально

Comment: Настройки вебпака вообще не трогал